# jquery fullcalender repeat events in all monday between two date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i have two dates: 26-02-2016 and 16-03-2016 and event repeat all monday and friday between these days

i am testing with this code but the second event repeat all monday and friday not considering the dates

```js
    events: [{
      "title": "Mark zuckerberg",
      "id": 41,
      "start": "2016-02-16T09:30",
      "end": "2016-02-16T10:30",
      "backgroundColor": "#1e92cd",
      "borderColor": "#1e92cd"
    }, {
      "title": "weakly",
      "id": "block",
      "start": "14:30",
      "end": "17:30",
      "backgroundColor": "#e7e7e7",
      "borderColor": "#e7e7e7",
      "dow": "[0,2,4,6]",
      "ranges": [{
        "start": "2016-02-24",
        "end": "2016-03-16"
      }, {
        "start": "2016-03-11",
        "end": "2016-04-16"
      }]
    }]
```